# C++,fstream, can I use multiple delimiter, if not how can I stop reading after a specifique delimiter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I want to read from a file but I am using multiple delimiter from in the same line, is there a way to change delimiter with getline, or a way to stop at a other delimiter

text:
1001#John#prog#200$500$700

```
Employee* readfile(){
    
    string str;


    Employee* Head = new Employee;

    
    ifstream myfile("empl.txt" , ios::binary);

    if ( !myfile ) { 
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);
    }

    Employee* tmp1 = new Employee;
    Employee* tmp2 = new Employee;
    
     cout<<"hello"<<endl;

    while (getline(myfile,str,'#')){
        
        cout<<str<<endl;
    
    }

    myfile.close();


    return Head;

}
```

Comment: !: I don't want to use vector library , I know its easier but I want to work without vectors.

Comment: To change delimiter, just pass something other then `#`. Nothing stops you from using different delimiters on different iterations of the loop. If you need better control, just read the whole line to a `std::string` and parse it with regex or `std::string::find`.

Comment: `getline(myfile,str,'#')` then `getline(myfile,str,'$')`

Comment: You can make the delimiter a variable and change that in your loop after the correct amount of variables have been read. A second option would be to use getline() to read a whole line into std::string and parse the string yourself.

Comment: @drescherjm how would I parse the string ?

Comment: Probably using `std::string::find` unless you are familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: Actual code for parsing will depend a lot on how you want to handle lines that do not conform to the format if it ever happens... And also if your separators are reserved for that purpose and cannot appears elsewhere... It looks like you are working with a text file too...